# Is there a custom URL scheme to open Google Chrome Beta on Android 2013 May

Tags: android, google-chrome

I need to know if a custom URL scheme is available for Google Chrome Beta on Android for latest version.

googlechrome://  will open Chrome  (not the beta version)

What will open  Chrome Beta on the Android?

Answer (score 2):

You can use an intent scheme like this:

> `intent:http://news.bbc.co.uk/#Intent;package=com.chrome.beta;end;`

Example at [jsbin.com/exujec/1/edit](http://jsbin.com/exujec/1/edit). (Thanks to Paul Kinlan for this.)

**Be aware that this is not a good technique for a production app. If the user does not have Chrome Beta installed, they will be directed to the Play Store (and Chrome Beta will not be found).**

Comment: Just to add, opening Custom URL schemes is not fully supported in the same way it was Android Browser does, so this is the method you should use.